# jQuery Live -- fire when item added to page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

I've got an Ajax update happening to my MVC view.  It displays a message telling the user the operation has completed:

```
<% if (ViewData["colorOptionsMessage"] != null) { %>
    <span class="ajaxMessage"><%= ViewData["colorOptionsMessage"] %></span>
<% } %>
```

I want to *atuomatically* fade this message out once it appears, and I'd like to do it once, and have it work site-wide.  This is what I tried, which doesn't work (the message appears, but the alert does not show):

```
$(function () {
   $(".ajaxMessage").live("load", function () { 
      alert("once I can get this to show I'll put in a jueryUI fadeOut"); });
});
```

**EDIT**

Just to be clear, I don't need help with the fade out code; I just need help getting this call to Live() to wire up properly.

Comment: I think this should be handled by the `success` callback of your AJAX function. The reason your `.live` event doesn't work, of course, is because `load` isn't a valid eventType for that.

Comment: Are you sure that "load" is the right event type? I'd rather try "change", as it should not fire on pageload, but after the AJAX update has changed something in your span.

Comment: In the ajax completion function, start your fadeOut.  You don't need to be monitor load events.  You should already have code running at the completion of the ajax call.  Just start the fadeOut there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct way to be informed automatically when new elements are added to the page. `$('.ajaxMessage').live('load')` would only happen when the `load` event fires on an image, iframe or object/embed/applet with `class="ajaxMessage"`, a `load` event is not fired with its own target for every new element that enters the page.

You could only do this by (a) [DOM Mutation Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents), which generally aren't widely enough supported, or (b) constantly polling to fetch the `.ajaxMessage` selector and seeing if any new elements appear in the results.

Better to manually `$('.ajaxMessage', function() {...})` immediately after (potentially) adding the content to the page, in the `ajax()` method's `success` handler.

ETA:

> that jQuery handler doesn't seem to execute after an ajaxForm success

If you can't catch `success` directly you could try registering a global success handler using [`ajaxSuccess`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/).

Comment: @DefyGravity: Don't get your hopes up, they're [en route to deprecation](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents) rather than broader support. But the effort is to make something better to take their place.

Answer (score 1):

The code below expects you made the Ajax call through jQuery.  if the ajax call was not through jQuery, then ignore this answer.  Could we see the ajax call itself?

```
 <Script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
// this is a jQuery global ajax event that fires for every ajax, you need to check the URL
       $.ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr, settings){
          if (settings.url == 'URI/ for/ajax /message/load.') {
          alert("once I can get this to show I'll put in a jueryUI fadeOut"); 
        }
       });
    );

    </script>
```

Comment: the .success message of the specific ajax call is best, fyi.  this is in case you are not in control of the original jQuery ajax call.

Comment: That actually would work great, but I'm using ASP.NET MVC 2, so that jQuery handler doesn't seem to execute after an ajaxForm success.  Pity, that would be ideal.  Having the superfluous calls to this handler wouldn't be a big deal since it would just result in a call to hide a non-existent message.  Thanks

Comment: never worked with asp.net mvc 2 yet. :(  can you wire the asp.net mvc 2 ajax call to trigger an event on the page before submitting the form?

Comment: It already provides a mechanism for a success callback, so I just need to make sure I put the appropriate script in each of the success callbacks.  It's not as good as what I wanted, but it's good enough.

Comment: or better, can it fire an event when it returns?  i'm thinking of adding a non-jquery event that the mvc 2 could fire upon return. inside that event you put some jQuery animations.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did.  I wrote a simple function hideMessage() and I call that from all of my MVC callbacks

Comment: It's just a simple Javascript function that has a line to $("...").fadeOut(6000);.  I call that function in all of my MVC success callbacks.  Really nothing to it.  The elegant write once method I was going for doesn't seem to be possible

Answer (score 0):

When i want to add something, wait a few, and hide it, I use setTimeout function instead of live events. I add the code on the success callback.

This is a 1 second wait:

```
setTimeout(function(){ $("ajaxMessage").fadeOut(); }, 1000)
```

Of course, if you dont want to wait, just fadeOut the element in the success callback.

Can this be enough for you?

Comment: What I was aiming for was to be able to *automatically* hide these messages *whenever* they're added.  But it doesn't look like this is possible.

Comment: It could be possible using AjaxSetup() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup
With ajaxSetup you can set some default behaviour to all ajax requests, including .ajaxSuccess() and .ajaxComplete()
This might solve your need, but for me, its more readable to put an explicit callback on every request. Or create a function that wraps this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can bind load to span.

only to **IMG IFRAME BODY**

Answer (score 0):

As I know "ready" and "load" events are not supported by jQuery in "live". So you can use plugins as this one [http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/announcing-jquery-live-ready-1-0-release/](http://cdn.bitbucket.org/larscorneliussen/jquery.liveready/downloads/demo.html)
Here is the demo http://cdn.bitbucket.org/larscorneliussen/jquery.liveready/downloads/demo.html