# Binding cycle plugin with .live() on window.load event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#breadcycle").live("window.onload", function () {
        $(this).cycle({
            fx: 'scrollUp',
            easing: 'easeOutBounce',
            speed: 1000,
            timeout: 2000
        });
    });
```

Whats the problem in this code. I am using `window.load`event for initializing cycle plugin with .live(). I tried this with document.ready also but same result not working.Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: `window.onload` there is no such event that is triggered for elements.

Comment: Note: `live()` is deprecated. Use `on()` instead (`.delegate()` under 1.7).

Comment: can u pls tell me the event on which i can load cycle with .live()

Comment: You can simply use `$("breadcycle").cycle({...});` inside document ready, why live ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Live -- fire when item added to page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773480/jquery-live-fire-when-item-added-to-page)

Comment: because in my slide show user can add images dynamically